# Laravel Returning 404s

Tags: php, apache, laravel

Ok, so I'm giving Laravel a go. Installed it, directories set up, everything good to go.

Alas, when I add

```
Route::get('users' function() {
    return "users!";
});
```

to routes.php and attempt to navigate to /users in my browser, I'm kicked back with a 404...`the requested url /users was not found on this server`.

I'm pretty sure it's a basic configuration thing, but I've got no idea what the exact cause is.

Any thoughts or pointers?

Comment: When you installed laravel and went to your site did you see "You've arrived' message?

Comment: Nope - I get an apache dir listing - rewrite is enabled btw

Comment: Maybe there are some problems with htaccess and mod_rewrite? You should've seen the message. There is nothing wrong with routes, so...

Comment: LAMP stack on ubuntu 12.04.3

Comment: You can setup a virtual host.

Comment: sudo a2enmod rewrite and AllowOverride All in your /sites-available/mysite config?

Comment: Is your Apache configuration (e.g. vhost) pointed at the /public directory, rather than just the laravel folder?

Comment: @Victor see above, rewrite already enabled

Comment: @JoelHinz negative, let me try that

Comment: working, great grand wonderful

Comment: Great! Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was ultimately an apache configuration oops. When setting up for Laravel, make sure your VirtualHost file (in /etc/apache2/sites-available/) has something resembling the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/laravel/public
        ServerName laravel.HidingMyDomainName.com
        ServerAlias www.laravel.HidingMyDomainName.com
</VirtualHost>
```

It should not be necessary to add an AllowOverride since the included .htaccess in the public dir contains this already.

Also of note, if Laravel was installed by another user, you could potentially run into a permission denied error. To fix this, simply `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/laravel/*` in your terminal of choice. Be aware of your default apache user, www-data is the default in Ubuntu server installations.